# Edit Button Visual State without Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

One can edit Foreground and Background etc... for a Button's default state without Blend using just the properties pane or code, but it is it possible to edit the colors for the other states without Blend?

For example,  all I want is a button to turn gray on "Mouse Over". Anything I have seen on Stack Overflow or on the Intertubes uses Blend. I want to do it without it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is using `Style` Triggers.

```
<Style x:Key="HoverButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The style is defined in your Resources.  And then when you define your button in XAML, you assign the style, like this:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Style="{DynamicResource HoverButtonStyle}"/>
```

This style will change the `Background` brush of your `Button` when the mouse is over it.  There are many more advanced things you can do with triggers, but this is a very simple example.  If you google WPF Style Triggers, you'll find many examples, including [this one](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html) which is pretty thorough.

There are other ways to do this, for example using the `VisualStateManager`, as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx), however if you're just trying to change the `Background` on hover, a style trigger is probably the simplest way.

Comment: Hey Brian! Good to see you again. Yeah this makes sense, but how do you know if a Property is "Triggerable" (can be used on a trigger)?

Comment: Hi @IsaiahNelson, good to see you too.  I believe any `DependencyProperty` can be used as the criteria `Property` for a `Trigger`.  And if you have multiple criteria, you can use a `MultiTrigger`.  As far as what can be changed within the `Trigger`, it is just like a `Style` setter, so you can assign any property values that you could in a `Style`.